# Embed not working JDA but my other embeds are

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

All my other commands work including my other embeds, but not this one, i havent done anything different so idk what went wrong, it might be because the description is too long but im not sure

```
EmbedBuilder topgearhorizonspecial = new EmbedBuilder();
      about.setTitle("I'm Chris Harris...");
      about.setDescription("I'm Chris Harris and this is the TopGear horizon special, ah yes, the stig, our very own UFO, unidentifed fast object, the worlds least obediant racing driver, right then the lotus elise a 90s classic based on the old age roadster recipie, 2 seats, engine in the middle, rear wheel drive, not an ounce of fat, this is what driving is all about");
      about.setColor(Color.magenta);
      
      if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "chrisharris")) {
          event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
          event.getChannel().sendMessage(topgearhorizonspecial.build()).queue();
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is accurate? You are not using the declared instance in your setters.  Your variable is called topgearhorizonspecial  but you are calling about.set...

Comment: wow im dumb
i copy/pasted the embed template from a !about and never changed the .set stuff. i need new eyes

Comment: @DiaDuck Another tip: Variables in java are commonly named using the `camelCase` variable naming scheme. (Every new word's first letter is capitalized, excluding first one) This will make your variables easier to read for you, and for us if you decide to post here in the future. This is obviously just a tip and is completely optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
EmbedBuilder topgearhorizonspecial = new EmbedBuilder();
      topgearhorizonspecial.setTitle("I'm Chris Harris...");
      topgearhorizonspecial.setDescription("I'm Chris Harris and this is the TopGear horizon special, ah yes, the stig, our very own UFO, unidentifed fast object, the worlds least obediant racing driver, right then the lotus elise a 90s classic based on the old age roadster recipie, 2 seats, engine in the middle, rear wheel drive, not an ounce of fat, this is what driving is all about");
      topgearhorizonspecial.setColor(Color.magenta);
      
      if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "chrisharris")) {
          event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
          event.getChannel().sendMessage(topgearhorizonspecial.build()).queue();
      }
```